# Where can I find the pandas datetime label/abreviation list/table?

Tags: pandas

Where can I find the pandas datetime label/abreviation list/table? Like ns=nanoseconds, H=hours and so on.

Comment: I think you are looking for python time directives. (https://strftime.org/) or (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html)

Comment: pandas docs lead you to the `datetime.strftime()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)